# Multiple folder with Json file of same name swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm facing difficulty to fetch the Json File.In my project there is one folder,in that folder multiple sub folders are there.And in every sub folder there is two json file.Json file name is common in every sub folder.Then how I fetch json file with subfolder name? Which means i want to differentiate json file through sub folder name.I'm new in Swift.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(NS)Bundle` provides a very convenient way to address subfolders, the optional parameter `subdirectory` of `url(forResource: withExtension:)`

```
if let jsonFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "jsonFile", 
                     withExtension: "json", 
                      subdirectory: "Subfolder1/SubFolder2") {

    let json = try! String(contentsOf: jsonFileURL, encoding: .utf8)
    print(json)

} else { fatalError("Check the file paths") }
```

Comment: Thanks for help.I have implemented but code is crashing with error:  fatal error: Check the file paths: file /Users/mac/Desktop/practise/UnzipFilePratice/UnzipFilePratice/ViewController.swift, line 25

Comment: Of course you have to change all literal paths to the actual ones in your bundle. Consider also that a yellow directory in Xcode is not a real directory in the file system. Those directories must be blue.

Comment: My folder name is English and subfolder name is opening..------------------------------------------
        if let jsonFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "content", withExtension: "txt",subdirectory: "English/opening")

Comment: Are you talking about the localized project folders? The operation system considers always the folder corresponding to the current language.

Comment: No.English is single folder and Inside English folder there are nine subfolders(opening,monday,tuesday....etc)

Comment: Don't put your custom data into the localized project folder. Create a subfolder in `Resources`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the file from different folders by providing the actual folder name in the document path.

Make sure that your files are added to resources.

```
 if let docsPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/Resources/subfolder" {
                let fileManager = FileManager.default

                do {
                    let docsArray = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docsPath)
                    //get the required json file from the documents array

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
```

}